# Exiting a program outside main function

Tags: c++, allegro

I m making a project with the allegro game library ,when the x button is clicked in the game
a function will be called ,i could then do std::exit(0) or the built in exit function of allegro "allegro_exit()" but my program won't exit well and it will be still open but not responding because i didn't return from the main function.

the only chance if i have is to do a while loop in the main function that performs stuff when the x button isn't clicked ,after the loop is done i could normally return from the main function,

however i don't think the while loop is good idea and it won't fit my program.

any chance of doing this in another way?

Comment: `std::exit` may run handlers which have been hooked in. To really exit without doing anything else you could go `std::signal(SIGABRT, SIG_DFL); std::abort();`  . This is not really a great idea IMHO, it would be preferably to `return` gracefully.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

`std::exit()` function does all necessary cleanups and terminates a program in a normal way. If your program freezes and doesn't respond then consider to carefully review the code that is responsible for resources releasing (destructors etc.). Some libraries can react to exit function in some strange way so take this case in account. You can read more about `std::exit()` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit).

Don't use `std::abort()` for normal program termination, because it is not aimed to be used for that and it doesn't cleanup after your application.

Anyway, I recommend you to review the architecture of your project and provide a return to the main function after all cleanups. `while` loop is ok, because it must exist somewhere to wait for user input.